# Java Facebook server to server get code URL parameter

Tags: java, facebook, oauth

I've been working on this for a couple of weeks now...

Basically what I am trying to do is login into Facebook (authenticate, accept the permissions, etc.), parse returned the "code" URL query param, and use that "code" param to get the FB user access token...

This is the FB_OAuthURL (for this example that is the name of the variable):

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<APP_ID>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&scope=public_profile%2Cpublish_actions%2Cuser_about_me%2Cuser_actions.books%2Cuser_actions.fitness%2Cuser_actions.music%2Cuser_actions.news%2Cuser_actions.video%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_education_history%2Cuser_events%2Cuser_games_activity%2Cuser_hometown%2Cuser_religion_politics%2Cuser_status%2Cuser_tagged_places%2Cuser_work_history%2Crsvp_event%2Cuser_relationships%2Cuser_relationship_details%2Cuser_location%2Cuser_likes%2Cuser_posts&state=<RANDOM_NUMBER>
```

The following is the method that I am using

```
public static String getFinalRedirectedUrl(String url) {
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        String finalUrl = url;
        try {
            do {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(finalUrl).openConnection();
                connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();
                if (connection.getResponseCode() >= 300 && responseCode < 400) {
                    String redirectedUrl = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
                    if (null == redirectedUrl)
                        break;
                    finalUrl = redirectedUrl;
                    System.out.println("redirected url: " + finalUrl);
                } else
                    break;
            } while (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return finalUrl;
    }
```

However the results (let's call this FB_REDIRCTURL) of this is the following:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=<APP_ID>&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.5%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%26state%3D-<RANDOM_NUMBER>%26scope%3Dpublic_profile%252Cpublish_actions%252Cuser_about_me%252Cuser_actions.books%252Cuser_actions.fitness%252Cuser_actions.music%252Cuser_actions.news%252Cuser_actions.video%252Cuser_birthday%252Cuser_education_history%252Cuser_events%252Cuser_games_activity%252Cuser_hometown%252Cuser_religion_politics%252Cuser_status%252Cuser_tagged_places%252Cuser_work_history%252Crsvp_event%252Cuser_relationships%252Cuser_relationship_details%252Cuser_location%252Cuser_likes%252Cuser_posts%26client_id%3D<APP_ID>%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26state%3D-4486902649550591089%23_%3D_&display=page
```

My two questions are

1. if I copy/paste this URL - the browser redirects me and I get the "code" param - again that is with me manually copying & pasting -- how do I get the method to move forward and eventually retrieve the http response that I am looking for
2. The FB_REDIRCTURL says that there was an error within the URL params, however, as I stated it still works when I copy & paste the url into a browser...any ideas why that is?

Thanks everyone -- I really appreciate the help

Comment: Login has to happen inside the browser, you can not do that “automatically” from within a script/program only.

Comment: Thanks CBroe -- I will keep trying